# i have mentioned in my Uk Standard Visa that my spouse will be travelling with me, but now she is not able to travel

Tags: uk, standard-visitor-visas

I have mentioned in my Uk Standard Visa that my spouse will be traveling with me, but now she is not able to travel and we are not applying for her Visa. Would this impact my application?

Comment: Have you already submitted your application? UKVI and Border Force understand that plans might change. As long as the changes don't significantly impact the premise of your visit or your personal circumstances, then you shouldn't be denied entry.

Comment: I have just applied for a standard visitor visa for the purpose of a business visit and my employer is sponsoring me.